# Is it possible the inorder traversal be the same order as the post-order traversal?

Tags: java, binary, binary-tree

For example, Let T be a binary tree:

Is it possible for the inorder traversal of T to be identical to the ***postorder*** traversal of T? if "yes" can you please give an example. And if "No" could you please explain why it cannot occur?

Also, Is it possible for the inorder traversal of T to be identical to the ***preorder*** traversal of T?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about algorithms and not specifically about programming. This question might be approrpiate for the [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it *possible*?  Yes.  Consider the inorder, preorder, and postorder traversal of the following tree

```
A
```

...that is, the tree consisting of exactly one node and no children.

This tree has the following traversal in inorder, preorder, and postorder: `[A]`.

In general, the inorder traversal is equivalent to the postorder traversal if there are only left children, and the inorder traversal is equivalent to the preorder traversal if there are only right children.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it possible for the inorder traversal of T to be identical to the
   **postorder** traversal of T?

Yes, when the tree only has a left child at every node:

```
                     a
                    / \
                   b  null
                  / \
                 c  null
                / \
               ...
```

2. Is it possible for the inorder traversal of T to be identical to the
   **preorder** traversal of T?

Yes, when the tree only has a right child at every node:

```
                     a
                    / \
                 null  b
                      / \
                   null  c
                        / \
                         ...
```

Look [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/100680) for a more detailed explanation.